# How ItemsControl textbox textchange event call?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, binding, user-controls

in general `TextBox` control `TextChanged` event is working but in `ItemsControl`, the `TextBox` `TextChanged` Event is not fired how can i do this. I trying to do by using following code which I have implemented but not getting result which I want.

So, what am I doing wrong?

**View**

```
<Window x:Class="SoniSoft.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ff="clr-namespace:SoniSoft"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.DataContext>
                <ff:ViewModels/>
            </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="38"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" ff:TextBoxBehaviour.TextChangedCommand="{Binding TextChanged}"  />

    <ItemsControl Margin="7,0,0,0" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewModelSearchResults}" x:Name="list">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBox  ff:TextBoxBehaviour.TextChangedCommand="{Binding TextChanged}" Text="{Binding Path=CategoryName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Normal" x:Name=" TextBoxCategoryName" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

**View Models**

```
class ViewModels :ViewModelBase
            {
                public ObservableCollection<Category> AllCategorys = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
                DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext();
                private ListCollectionView _objViewModelSearchResults;
                public ListCollectionView ViewModelSearchResults
                {
                    get { return _objViewModelSearchResults; }
                    set
                    {
                        _objViewModelSearchResults = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("ViewModelSearchResults");
                    }
                }
                public ViewModels()
                {
                    AllCategorys.Clear();
                    foreach (var item in db.Categories.OrderBy(c => c.CategoryName))
                    {
                        AllCategorys.Add(item);
                    }
                    ViewModelSearchResults = new ListCollectionView(AllCategorys);
                }
                public ICommand TextChanged
                {
                    get
                    {
                        //  this is very lazy: I should cache the command!
                        return new TextChangedCommand();
                    }
                }
        private class TextChangedCommand : ICommand
                {
                    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
                    public void Execute(object parameter)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Text Changed");
                    }

                    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

**DependencyProperty**

```
class EventBehaviourFactory
                {
                    public static DependencyProperty CreateCommandExecutionEventBehaviour(RoutedEvent routedEvent, string propertyName, Type ownerType)
                    {
                        DependencyProperty property = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(propertyName, typeof(ICommand), ownerType,
                                                                           new PropertyMetadata(null,
                                                                               new ExecuteCommandOnRoutedEventBehaviour(routedEvent).PropertyChangedHandler));

                        return property;
                    }
    private class ExecuteCommandOnRoutedEventBehaviour : ExecuteCommandBehaviour
                    {
                        private readonly RoutedEvent _routedEvent;

                        public ExecuteCommandOnRoutedEventBehaviour(RoutedEvent routedEvent)
                        {
                            _routedEvent = routedEvent;
                        }

                        /// <summary>
                        /// Handles attaching or Detaching Event handlers when a Command is assigned or unassigned
                        /// </summary>
                        /// <param name="sender"></param>
                        /// <param name="oldValue"></param>
                        /// <param name="newValue"></param>
                        protected override void AdjustEventHandlers(DependencyObject sender, object oldValue, object newValue)
                        {
                            UIElement element = sender as UIElement;
                            if (element == null) { return; }

                            if (oldValue != null)
                            {
                                element.RemoveHandler(_routedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(EventHandler));
                            }

                            if (newValue != null)
                            {
                                element.AddHandler(_routedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(EventHandler));
                            }
                        }

                        protected void EventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                        {
                            HandleEvent(sender, e);
                        }
                    }

                    internal abstract class ExecuteCommandBehaviour
                    {
                        protected DependencyProperty _property;
                        protected abstract void AdjustEventHandlers(DependencyObject sender, object oldValue, object newValue);

                        protected void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
                        {
                            DependencyObject dp = sender as DependencyObject;
                            if (dp == null)
                            {
                                return;
                            }

                            ICommand command = dp.GetValue(_property) as ICommand;

                            if (command == null)
                            {
                                return;
                            }

                            if (command.CanExecute(e))
                            {
                                command.Execute(e);
                            }
                        }

                        /// <summary>
                        /// Listens for a change in the DependencyProperty that we are assigned to, and
                        /// adjusts the EventHandlers accordingly
                        /// </summary>
                        /// <param name="sender"></param>
                        /// <param name="e"></param>
                        public void PropertyChangedHandler(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
                        {
                            // the first time the property changes,
                            // make a note of which property we are supposed
                            // to be watching
                            if (_property == null)
                            {
                                _property = e.Property;
                            }

                            object oldValue = e.OldValue;
                            object newValue = e.NewValue;

                            AdjustEventHandlers(sender, oldValue, newValue);
                        }
                    }

                }

             class TextBoxBehaviour
                {
                    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextChangedCommand = EventBehaviourFactory.CreateCommandExecutionEventBehaviour(TextBox.TextChangedEvent, "TextChangedCommand", typeof(TextBoxBehaviour));

                    public static void SetTextChangedCommand(DependencyObject o, ICommand value)
                    {
                        o.SetValue(TextChangedCommand, value);
                    }

                    public static ICommand GetTextChangedCommand(DependencyObject o)
                    {
                        return o.GetValue(TextChangedCommand) as ICommand;
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: i have posted my code. @Shoaib Shaikh

Comment: CardViewModelSearchResults Items will be handling textchange event. where is CardViewModelSearchResults property in ViewModel?

Comment: it's ListCollectionView ViewModelSearchResults collaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem. You are setting the command in an ItemTemplate. Thus it is binding to the `Category` object you have in the `ListCollectionView`. Now this is the object that doesnt contain any command for your text changed. What does contain the command for your `TextChanged` is the DataContext of the `UserControl` and you need to bind it to that.

Now there are is a way to work around and its called `Ancestor` `RelativeSource`. As I work with silverlight it might work different but this line of code should do.

**Edit:**

The actual line should be. this because it is ofcourse a window and you need to have the DataContext (the viewmodel) and then the property `TextChanged`:

```
<TextBox ff:TextBoxBehaviour.TextChangedCommand="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Path=DataContext.TextChanged}" />
```

Comment: I have impliment this code.simple textbox textchanged event working  but in ItemControl TextBox TextChanged Event is not working. - @Rikkos

Comment: of course my bad. ill put in a edit that will work. Ive created a sample project to test this. - @Tulsi

Comment: @Tulsi Your welcome, dont forget to mark the question as answered